# How can I implement the calculation of the duration between Value 1 and 0 within one field in splunk?

Tags: duration, splunk, splunk-query

How can I calculate the duration between the value 1 and 0 of one common field? The duration should be summed up with the following calculations of the durations, too. 
In the picture you can see the initial situation (first two columns), you get out of the base search! In the right two columns, the time-calculation should be calculated.

Code:
| base search
--> then you get the result, which you can see in the first two columns at the picture.

[Description of the problem!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHwBR.png)

Answer (score 0):

@schiggy

Can you please try this?

`YOUR_SEARCH | transaction startswith="variableX=1" endswith="variableX=0" 
| table _time duration 
| stats sum(duration) as total_duration`

**My Sample Search:**

`| makeresults count=10 
| eval diff=10 
| accum diff 
| eval variableX=if(diff%20==0,0,1) 
| eval _time=now()-diff 
| table _time variableX 
| transaction startswith="variableX=1" endswith="variableX=0" 
| table _time duration 
| stats sum(duration) as total_duration 
| eval total_duration=tostring(total_duration, "duration")`

Comment: Thank you very much. You've helped me a lot.

Comment: Glad to help you. If your problem is resolved then can you please accept and upvote this answer to close this question?